# How to add a large data structure saved in a .js file to API.AI

Tags: javascript, facebook, heroku, dialogflow-es

I've created a `facebook messenger bot`. I did it initially via command line, `heroku` and `javascript`, but after researching how to add a maps functionality, I stumbled accross a neat little tool called `API.AI` which is a machine learning natural language processing tool for messenger bots and the likes.

This tool also has access to maps functionality and has a great and easy way of dealing with user queries, rather than having several hundred `if-else` statements in my javascript index file. The only problem is, I have a larged stored data structure of objects that are required for the messenger bot, i.e

Several hundred objects like this

```
var obj = {

name : x , 

location : x ,

url : x 

};
```

and i cant see any way for me to easily store all of these objects in the `API.AI` structure without individually one by one adding them in to the `entities` category. This could take hours as I have hundres of these objects stored in my file.

Any API.AI developers out there know of any way I can easily and quickly add all of the objects to my API.AI bot, or to save time should I just learn how to integrate maps acoustically via javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the idea is that you would use fulfillment webhooks to hit your own server for this data. You receive the intent, entities, and context which you then respond with your json object contain the body message to be sent to the user.

https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook